# jQuery toggles hides element on document.load

Tags: jquery, toggle

For some reason my ".ddls" gets hidden when the document loads although this is all the scripting I have:

```
<div class="code">
    <a href="#" class="ddls" data-clicked="no">Spotify</a>
    <a href="#" class="ddls" data-clicked="no">YouTube</a>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ddls").toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
        $(this).attr("data-clicked", "yes");
        console.log("hehe");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hovered");
        $(this).attr("data-clicked", "no");
        console.log("haha");
    });
});
</script>
```

You can see it live at http://haakon.underbakke.net/musikk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `toggle()` is deprecated - api.jquery.com/toggle-event

You can refactor to use a simple `click` event:

```
$(".ddls").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hovered");
    var clickedAttr = $(this).attr("data-clicked") == "yes" ? "no" : "yes";
    $(this).attr("data-clicked", clickedAttr);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand .toggle(). See the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

On document ready, you toggle the visibility of elements with class "ddls"... the two functions you pass in are most likely getting thrown away by the jQuery toggle function (since they don't map to any parameters defined for it (see documentation above).

It sounds like you want to add a click listener to $(".ddls"), and to toggle class "hover" and data-clicked attribute when it's clicked:

```
$(".ddls").click(function () {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.toggleClass("hovered");
  if (elem.attr('data-clicked') === 'yes') {
    elem.attr('data-clicked', 'no');
  } else {
    elem.attr('data-clicked', 'yes');
  } 
});
```

See:
http://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/